# Django rest framework. Return multiple models nested

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a combined viewset that displays data in a nested format from three django models.

I'm receiving an error when I try to return the viewset.

`` Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `runner` on serializer `CombinedSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Runner` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Runner' object has no attribute 'runner'. ``

serializers.py

```
class CombinedSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    event = EventSerializer()
    market = MarketSerializer()
    runner = RunnerSerializer()
    class Meta:
        fields = ('event' , 'market', 'runner')
```

views.py

```
class CombinedViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, 
                      viewsets.GenericViewSet, 
                     mixins.RetrieveModelMixin):

    queryset = Runner.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CombinedSerializer
```

models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    sport_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    event_id = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=13)


class Market(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    market_id = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    market_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    volume = models.FloatField(null=True)

class Runner(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    runner_id = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    back_odds = models.FloatField(null=True)
    lay_odds = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

For some reason when I remove runner from the serializer Event and Market display in my api in nested format. When I add Runner I get the above error. How can I fix this and display all three in my API?

Comment: The serializer thinks that "Combined Serializer" is serializing the "Runner" model. Becuase "Runner" is the queryset. Try taking runner out, but then rather listing all the fields that you want from your runner model in the "fields" tuple.

Comment: @Neil If I add the fields from runner model in fields tuple how does the serializer know that those fields belong to the runner model since it's not referenced? I've taken out runner and tried to add the fields and I don't get any data from runners back in the api response.

Comment: It is referenced behind the scenese. DRF does quite a lot. When the view calls the serializer it passes in the queryset. Do you get an error, or do you just not get any data?

Comment: @Neil I've no idea to be honest. I don't normally work with DRF. I got no data and no error

Comment: Add your models, so we can help you with the setup of the viewset/serializer

Comment: @Fran thanks for your comment. I've added my models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `quesryset` in the `ViewSet` contains the `Runner` instances:

```
queryset = Runner.objects.all()
```

But in the `CombinedSerializer` you have included the `runner` field (mapped to the `RunnerSerailizer`) -- you already have a `Runner` model instance so you don't have `runner` field in there, you only have the fields that are available in the `Runner` model, any reverse-related fields, and custom fields that you've added on the serializer.

---

You have a couple of options:

Inherit from `ModelSerializer` and include all the fields:

```
class CombinedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    event = EventSerializer()
    market = MarketSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Runner
        fields = '__all__'
```

Or if you want more granular control over your fields, mention the fields explicitly (you can keep the `Serializer` inheritence in this case) e.g.:

```
class CombinedSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    event = EventSerializer()
    market = MarketSerializer()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('event', 'market', 'name', 'back_odds')
```

If you want to inherit from `serializers.ModelSerializer`, you need to mention the model in the `Meta` class:

```
class CombinedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    event = EventSerializer()
    market = MarketSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Runner
        fields = ('event', 'market', 'name', 'back_odds')
```